# when to use clustered index and when to use nonclustered index

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thanks for giving the time to read my question .
i have a question in my mind that 
`**when we should use clustered and nonclustered index**`.
i have searched on the internet and found that clustered index is much 
faster than the nonclustered index. 
but i am confused about the usage circumstances .
can you please tell me when we should use clustered and when we should 
 use nonclustered index.
Looking for your kind help.

Thanks in advance .
Pooja

Comment: Read the linked thread, especially Martin Smith's answer is really comprehensive and well explained!

Comment: Hi ahmed, thanks for providing the link. But my question is if clustered index is faster than nonclustered index then what should be the cases or situations when we should use the nonclustered index

Comment: Did you read the linked thread? In almost all cases **there is no general answer to the question *Which is faster?* - It depends...**

Comment: Just one example: A clustered index on a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` will be quite bad probably (high fragmentation), while a clustered index on an insert datetime value will be very fast if you search for a date range...